# References for Schonhage-strassen multiplication

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

**Original Title: Schonhage-strassen multiplication in detail**

I found some materials to understand Schönhage-Strassen algorithm (SSA), but some details exist that I cannot understand.

I am studying it with:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGUMsBkZqkc&t=833s
[http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~eberly/Courses/CPSC667/2008/Notes/schonhage_strassen.pdf](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/%7Eeberly/Courses/CPSC667/2008/Notes/schonhage_strassen.pdf)

It seems like Schönhage-Strassen algorithm is a way to compute (given two integers A and B with sizes of 'n') A$*$B mod$(2^n+1)$, not A*B

My question is, how can I get A$*$B  from  A*B mod$(2^n+1)$

---

Edit) I am trying to understand how two integers can be multiplied faster with Schonhage-strassen multiplication, but references above are not working for me.
Are there other references for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it is mod($2^n+1$)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGUMsBkZqkc&t=833s

Comment: I am asking you to write in detail in your questions what you think SSA is including the mod($2^n + 1$) part and then we can tell where you went wrong.

Comment: I pressed enter by my mistake and don't know how to edit it.. sorry..  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGUMsBkZqkc&t=833s, the lecture here, z=u*v mod(2^n+1), he showed how to compute z, and did not compute u*v. Also in here, http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~eberly/Courses/CPSC667/2008/Notes/schonhage_strassen.pdf, w = u*v mod(2^n+1), and w is not u*v. I think there should be a way to compute u*v from w

Comment: It may be best to  change you original question to ask for good references for the SSA. The YouTube lectures are not working for you. There are alternate sources so ask for them.

Comment: Thanks you Somos! :)

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm)? Notice the phrase "Given input numbers x and y, and an integer N, the following algorithm computes the product xy mod $2^N + 1$. Provided N is sufficiently large this is simply the product." Note the "sufficiently large".

Comment: I did, but it is difficult for me to understand. The YouTube lecture SSA and algorithm explained in wikipedia are different (ie, YouTube lecture SSA uses DFT+chinese remainder Theorem, and Wikipedia SSA, which I did not understand fully, only uses DFT). Anyway I also found https://psun.me/post/fft2/ and it seems helpful for me.